# framework_go_proto missing while building TensorFlow for Go

Tags: tensorflow

Followed instructions on [tensorflow-go-intsall](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/go/README.md) to build tensorflow for go. 
All goes well until I hit a point where I need to generate wrapper functions for ops.

Environment:

- OS X
- go version 1.9.2
- tensorflow(master branch)
- protoc version 3.5.1

Command:

```
go generate github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/op
```

Problem:

> cannot find package "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/tensorflow/core/framework_go_proto"

Comment: I'm having this issue now. Was this ever resolved, @ms ghotra, or is this an ongoing issue?

Comment: This sounds like a bug which should be filed on github

Comment: Yes, I will file this.